# AWS Lambda: Stream a response body?

Tags: aws-lambda, boto3, aws-serverless

I would like to create a Lambda function that converts a video on the fly and, and streams the output to the user as it's being converted. This is to prevent any initial wait times.

I know how to do the video conversion part using ffmpeg and stdout, but am unclear if Lambda can even stream output, or if it always needs the full response body to be complete.

Is it possible to stream out a Response Body in Lambda? Any Python examples?

Comment: Any luck on this?

Comment: @Arman, no it doesn't seem to be possible